# AWS S3 List Objects Access Denied On EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, bucket

Iam new to AWS and now Iam facing the access denied problem when excuted

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket BUCKET_NAME
```

Here are what I configured:

- IAM role: attach AmazonS3FullAccess policy
- EC2: attach above IAM role
- Bucket:

  - Block all public access: OFF
  - Policy: allow all action
  - ACL: OFF
  - Other setting: default

IAM Role policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllActionsForUsersWhoCanList",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: **Warning:** The Bucket Policy you have shown grants **everyone in the world** access to your S3 bucket. They can list the contents, upload objects, download objects and even delete the bucket! I recommend that you remove this Bucket Policy _immediately!_

Comment: The IAM Policy you have shown is sufficient to access all bucket in your AWS account. You should start by confirming that the IAM Role is being used by the EC2 instance -- you can run `aws sts get-caller-identity` to "return details about the IAM user or role whose credentials are used to call the operation". If it shows that you are using the correct role, the next question is whether the S3 bucket belongs to the same AWS account as the credentials being used. What happens if you run `aws s3 ls`? Do you see that bucket?

Comment: Minor: you should be using `list-objects-v2` rather than `list-objects`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
Thank you, John Rotenstein. The EC2 instance is using the correct IAM role, and aws s3 ls successfully displays a list of buckets

Comment: Is the bucket you are wanting to use included in that list of buckets? Do the objects appear if you use `aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET_NAME`?

Comment: Yes, @JohnRotenstein, the list includes my bucket. However, when I run `aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET_NAME`, it still tells me access denied.

Comment: Something is indeed strange. Are you able to view the content of _other_ buckets?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
No, I can view everything in the bucket via the console, but not via the CLI

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
I have modified the IAM role policy. However, now the `aws s3 ls` is not working
`
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
`

Comment: The IAM Role policy you had was fine (a bit over-generous, but it would have worked). If you run `aws s3 ls s3://ANOTHER_BUCKET` can you view the contents of a different bucket? This will help us identify whether the problem is related to one bucket, or every bucket.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256359/discussion-between-shin622-and-john-rotenstein).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying numerous solutions, I finally realized that the problem was with my VPC endpoint to S3. There was a policy limiting access to resources. I want to express special thanks to John Rotenstein, who provided me with a lot of advice[image]